# Batch: All lines above number skip are shown, when only the line number skip is needed

Tags: loops, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that converts a list of names to a username in the format of (Lastname)(First letter of first name) e.g Robert Smith -> SmithR
I've got most of it sorted, but I'm having a problem where it loops the lines in the text document, and I'm not sure why it's doing that. I was wondering if you guys could tell me how to fix it

Thanks in advance ^-^

CODE: http://pastebin.com/zDtJrPrV
NAMES: http://pastebin.com/xbh3WTSv

Answer (score 1):

Your script is full of inefficiencies and is much longer than it needs to be.  Your first `for /f` loop suffers from a useless use of `findstr` which would actually do more harm than good if your names file contains any blank lines.  And initiating a new `for /f "skip=N"` for each line of the names file will cause the file to be opened, read, and closed for every iteration when it really only needs to be opened once.  And it's more graceful to use `find /c` to count the number of lines in a text file.

Here, salt this to taste:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "names=names.txt"
set "outfile=outfile.txt"

for /f %%I in ('find "" /v /c ^< "%names%"') do set /a "lines=%%I"

choice /c YN /n /m "Preparing to process %lines% lines.  Continue? (y/n) "

if errorlevel 2 goto :EOF

>"%outfile%" (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1*" %%I in ("%names%") do (
        set "first=%%I"
        echo %%J!first:~0,1!
    )
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: +1 Just to add a pinch of pepper, `for /f %%I in ('find "" /v /c ^< "%names%"') ...` is more efficient than `for /f %%I in ('type "%names%" ^| find "" /v /c') ...` **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini Thanks!  Implemented.